# How to convert from getInputStream to DataInputStream

Tags: java, proxy

I've got a java proxy and I just need to convert from using getInputStream and start using DataInputStream.

This is the code to start the stream.

```
private Socket socket;
private static OutputStream os;
private InputStream is;

private byte[] request = new byte[1024];

public Client(Socket clientSocket) throws IOException {
    socket = clientSocket;
    is = socket.getInputStream();
    os = socket.getOutputStream();
    Log.logInfo("* Client connected");
}
```

What do I need to change from that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using a [DataInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) constructor. Using the constructor you can covert easily a [InputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) to a DataOutputStream.

Now You have the InputStream `is` which you have get from the `socket.getInputStream()` method. You can construct your `DataOutputSTream` using the following code snippet -

```
DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(is);
```

Hope it will help.
Thanks

Comment: add after `is = socket.getInputStream();` this line

Comment: Did yo forget import statement?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
DataInputStream streamIn = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));
```

Comment: Where do I put it? What do i replace it with.

Comment: Put it after `is = socket.getInputStream();`

Comment: Nope, getting errors with the BufferedInputStream part and at new datainputstream,

Comment: In this case I am not sure is it is required to convert the `InputStream` to `BufferedInputStream` (just asking..) ?

Comment: Try pass the InputSteam directly into the DataInputStream constructor like this: `DataInputStream streamIn = new DataInputStream(is);` What errors are you getting?

Comment: Errors: `                DateInputStream streamIn = new DataInputStream(is);
                ^
  symbol:   class DateInputStream
  location: class Client
com\webraid\cocproxy\network\Client.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
                DateInputStream streamIn = new DataInputStream(is);
                                               ^
  symbol:   class DataInputStream
  location: class Client.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
                os = socket.DataOutputStream();
                           ^
  symbol:   method DataOutputStream()
  location: variable socket of type Socket`

Comment: Sorry I misspelled DataInputStream. Change Date to Data in DataInputStream.

Comment: It's a compilation error? Am I right? If so did you forget the import DataInputStream

Comment: Yes, I forgot to import it!